# Shall I mention the deep links in the sample invocation in the directory page?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am making an action for google assistant.I have created some deep links so should I mention them in the sample invocations in the directory information? I also want the users to see the first welcome screen that is the default welcome intent and not directly jump to the other intents for the first time.I cannot decide what to do.Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing them in your examples lets people know that the feature is possible.

If you really don't want to allow it when they first start - you can intercept the "deep link" at invocation time and send back a reply welcoming them first and explaining things, then either letting them do it or letting them do it in the future.